# (Gradle) ClassNotFoundException when running testNG test task for new source set

Tags: java, build, gradle, gradlew

I have my own source set that uses some of the main sources:

```
sourceSets {
    special {
            java {
                source main.java
            }
    }
```

I made sure that it can be compiled and run properly:

```
configurations {

    specialCompile.extendsFrom(compile)
    specialRuntime.extendsFrom(runtime)

}
```

And have my own test task for it:

```
task heavyTest(type: Test) {
    useTestNG()         
    testClassesDir  = project.sourceSets.special.output.classesDir
    testSrcDirs    += project.sourceSets.special.java.srcDirs.toList()
}
```

Special source contains test methods in class org.me.ImportantTests

Compilation works and tests runs succesfully in eclipse as well, yet when i try to execute heavyTest task from gradle it fails

```
01:18:23.360 [ERROR] [system.err] 01:18:23.357 [ERROR] [system.err] [TestNG] [ERROR] No test suite found. Nothing to run
01:18:23.488 [QUIET] [system.out] 01:18:23.486 [QUIET] [system.out] Usage: <main class> [options] The XML suite files to run
```

running with -d reveals that gradle encountered ClassNotFoundException:

```
01:18:23.559 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         Caused by:
01:18:23.559 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not load test class 'org.me.ImportantTests'.
01:18:23.560 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.testng.TestNGTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(TestNGTestClassProcessor.java:67)
01:18:23.561 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:49)
01:18:23.561 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             ... 21 more
01:18:23.561 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]
01:18:23.562 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             Caused by:
01:18:23.563 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.me.ImportantTests
```

It looks like the .class file is not in the classpath... but I set testClassesDir properly and the class is exactly where it shold be (/org/me/ImportantTests.class)! What is wrong with this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I noticed i can fix this in the following way:

```
task integTest2(type: Test) {
    useTestNG()
    testClassesDir  = project.sourceSets.special.output.classesDir
    classpath = classpath.plus(files(testClassesDir))
    testSrcDirs    += project.sourceSets.special.java.srcDirs.toList()
}
```

This works, but looks quite... stupid. Why do I need to tell the test task, that directory with classes to test should be on the classpath? "Please test classes that are in that directory. Oh, by the way, to load them, try looking in the directory in which they are". Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The test runtime class path typically contains *much* more than the test classes dir.

Comment: Yeah.. but why it does not contain test classes dir by default?

Comment: `classpath` is the full class path, and hence also needs to contain the test classes. `testClassesDir` is additional, optional information used for purposes such as test class scanning.

Comment: Optional? Will the task be able to do any testing if this information is not provided? It might be a good idea to put that into documentation (or just add setting this property and classpath to examples on DSL ref page) to avoid any confusion.

Comment: I think it is, if you disable test class scanning and use include/exclude filters instead. Usually it's better to provide `testClassesDir` though.

Comment: Oh yeah this is another thing - the description of "scanForTestClasses" is hardly understandable for me. However it looks like exlude/include patterns are always used. 
Also it seems that classes (output) directory for main and test source sets are always on Test tasks classpath - is it intended?

Comment: What's on the test task's class path is solely determined by the party(s) configuring the task (e.g. the `java` plugin). Include/exclude patterns are used if they are present (none are added by the `java` plugin).

Comment: I see. Oh well, even though I have issues with this design I won't argue with it, I guess it allows greater flexibility (which is one of the big winning points of gradle for me in current, classpaths and classloaders meddling, project). The Test task could definitely get use of having its documentation a bit expanded to spare other people confusion and issues that I have encountered. Thanks for your help Peter.